# Reactive Forms async validator is called before component variables are populated

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

So what I'm trying to do is validate if username is already taken or not in my user edit form.
Here is my form:

```
editForm= new FormGroup({
                username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(60)], this.validateUser.bind(this)),
                fullName: new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(60)),
                email: new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(60)),
                phoneNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(60)),
            }, { updateOn: "blur"});
```

In my validator I check if original username is changed before sending validation request by comparing it to variable which has user info loaded from server:

```
validateUser(control: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    if(control.value != this.originUser.username){
        return this.userService.validateUsername(control.value).pipe(map(res => {
            return res['valid'] ? null : { invalidUsername: true};
        }));
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if I try to change username to already taken by another user and I get an error. Also if after this I change it to original username it also works fine and validation request is not sent.

My `this.originUser` is populated in `ngOnInit` and this happens after validator is called for the first time on form initialization so I still see a validation request with original username is sent and get an error when form loads with original username.

```
ngOnInit() {
            this.userService.getOne(this.id).subscribe(user =>{
                this.editForm.patchValue({
                    username: user.username,
                    fullName: user.fullName,
                    email: user.email,
                    phoneNumber:user.phoneNumber
                });
                this.originUser = user;
            });
        }
    }
```

I cant figure out the logic how not to send validation request when validator is called for the first time when I open "Edit user" page

**UPD:**
I figured out how not to get error on form load by adding `this.editForm.get('username').updateValueAndValidity();` after i load `this.originUser` in `ngOnInit` but unnecessary validation request is still sent when form loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was quite simple
Added `control.dirty` to validator condition so request is never sent if user didnt change the input

```
validateUsername(control: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    if(control.value != this.originUser.username && control.dirty){
        return this.userService.validateUsername(control.value).pipe(map(res => {
            return res['valid'] ? null : { invalidUsername: true};
        }));
    } else return of({});
}
```